# Cucumber new paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber

The answer for this question should be trivial. Is there any way to get in to the show action path to a given AR object within cucumber paths.(I am using factories to set up test AR objects).

I can refer in paths.rb new, edit and index paths but when it comes to show action it needs to specify the object and is there a way to refer that object on the paths.rb

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entierly sure I understand the question - you want to be able to visit the 'show' page for a specific instance of a model?

Would somethign like this work? (taken from features/support/paths.rb)

```
when /the profile page for "([^\"]*)"/
  user_path(User.find_by_username($1))
```

In this case, you will visit the 'show' action (profile page) of the username supplied in the Scenario.